# FileHelpers writing a CSV with line breaks within the fields

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, line-breaks, filehelpers

Using FileHelpers, my C# application reads a CSV and then processes the data. After processing, the data is written as another CSV. The output CSV has got line breaks within some fields. How can those be avoided?

Comment: I don't think your question is clear enough. By avoided, do you mean removed?  Are the line breaks in the original CSV? Are the line breaks actual \n\r breaks, or is the editor you are looking at the CSV with just soft-wrapping the file?

Answer (score 2):

FileHelpers does not automatically remove line breaks before writing the CSV. It's easy to do with a [custom converter](http://www.filehelpers.com/example_customconv.html). Here's a working example.

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public partial class MyClass
{
    [FieldConverter(typeof(MyStringConverter))]
    [FieldQuoted('"')]
    public String Field1;
    [FieldConverter(typeof(MyStringConverter))]
    [FieldQuoted('"')]
    public String Field2;
}      

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<MyClass>();
        var myClass1 = new MyClass();
        myClass1.Field1 = "Dear Sir,\n Blah blah blah";
        myClass1.Field2 = "Yours sincerely,\n George";
        var output = engine.WriteString(new MyClass[]{myClass1});
        Assert.AreEqual(@"""Dear Sir, Blah blah blah"",""Yours sincerely, George""" + Environment.NewLine, output);
    }
}

public class MyStringConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override string FieldToString(object from)
    {
        string output = base.FieldToString(from);
        // remove any line breaks before outputting
        output = output.Replace("\n", "");
        output = output.Replace("\r", "");
        return output;
    }

    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
        return from;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the Log4Net solution suggested [here](http://element533.blogspot.ie/2010/05/writing-to-csv-using-log4net.html), and it works but it's not the fastest. That said, I'm using it to write hundreds of thousands of lines...

Answer (score -2):

CSV is by its nature line based. So you cannot have real line breaks in your data. You can encode them with something like the literal "\n" (expressed literally in the file as \n) and then when you parse the file later, you would need to replace the literal with the actual line break.